# Jhipster and new project

Tags: yeoman, jhipster

I have one project in jhipster. But I want generate new project and I don't know how do this. When i run in terminal   `yo jhpister` yeoman begins edit my current project. 
How I can remove my old project, or how I can start new project in jhpister.

Comment: As Gael explained you need to create a project in new directory. Of you want to see more about next steps. You can check one o the of online tutorials - e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1MEM8PdAzQ

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new project directory, cd to this directory and run `yo jhpister`.  If you want to use similar settings to your last project, copy .yo-rc.json from your old project to your new one and it'll generate with the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Cmd Prompt
2. Go to the Directory(C or E or D ) your wish
3. Type  `mkdir mySampleProject`
4. then `cd mySampleProject`
5. After that you can Give `yo jhipster`

Now you can able to Create new Project .